# iOS table view - I don't know if this is even possible

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

In table view with many rows, is it possible to have the top row (row[0]) "frozen",
while the rest of the rows 'scroll' up an down..  If you have any hints about this, it would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this would be to use a section header as the top row. Otherwise, do the top row as a separate UI element.

Comment: This might work fine if your rows aren't selectable (tappable). If you are going for full interactive functionality you will probably need 2 tables stacked vertically with the upper table containing the header (if desired) and the lower table being the "rest" of the table.